# Rshiny : Add a free text for comments

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data coming from a server. Now I want to add a free text column ( editable) to add comments to my R shiny application. Once that is done , I want to save it in SQLLite and bring it back once it is refreshed. Please help me with the pointers.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "diamonds"'
     
      )
   
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
       
      )
    )
  )
)

library(DT)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

  
  diamonds2$test <- ifelse(diamonds2$x > diamonds2$y,TRUE,FALSE)
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds2[, drop = FALSE],extensions = 'FixedColumns',options = list(
      dom = 't',
      scrollX = TRUE,
      fixedColumns = list(leftColumns =10)
    )) %>%
      
    formatStyle(
      'x', 'test',
      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(TRUE, FALSE), c('gray', 'yellow'))
    )
    
  })
  
 
  
}
```

Please guide how can I add free text in the end of the table and save it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
R

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812512/how-to-edit-and-save-changes-made-on-shiny-datatable-using-dt-package

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on DTs `editable` option. (See [this](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/480) for more information)

Each time the user edits a cell in the "comment" column it is saved to a sqlite database and loaded again after restarting the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)  # diamonds dataset
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

# choose columns to display
diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000),]
diamonds2$test <- ifelse(diamonds2$x > diamonds2$y, TRUE, FALSE)
diamonds2$id <- seq_len(nrow(diamonds2))
diamonds2$comment <- NA_character_

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "diamonds.db")

if(!"diamonds" %in% dbListTables(con)){
  dbWriteTable(con, "diamonds", diamonds2)  
}

ui <- fluidPage(title = "Examples of DataTables",
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                  conditionalPanel('input.dataset === "diamonds"')
                ),
                mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                  id = 'dataset',
                  tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
                ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # use sqlInterpolate() for production app
  # https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sql-injections.html
  dbDiamonds <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM diamonds;")
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      dbDiamonds,
      # extensions = 'FixedColumns',
      options = list(
        dom = 't',
        scrollX = TRUE
        # , fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 10)
      ),
      editable = TRUE,
      # editable = list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = which(names(diamonds2) %in% setdiff(names(diamonds2), "comment"))))
    ) %>% formatStyle('x', 'test', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(TRUE, FALSE), c('gray', 'yellow')))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$mytable1_cell_edit, {
    if(input$mytable1_cell_edit$col == which(names(dbDiamonds) == "comment")){
      dbExecute(con, sprintf("UPDATE diamonds SET comment = '%s' WHERE id = %s", input$mytable1_cell_edit$value, input$mytable1_cell_edit$row))
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, onStart = function() {
  onStop(function() {
    dbDisconnect(con) # close connection on app stop
  })
})
```

Initially I wanted to disable editing for all columns except "comment", however, it seems I've [found a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/928).

Comment: I was thinking originally in the same direction, but the solution is buggy. try to change any other column but "comment" and at least on my system the value disappears.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system (No values are disappearing). As mentioned above I'd prefer disabling editing for all other columns, however, this needs a fix.

Comment: Here is a GIF showing what I meant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvMRf.gif. COuld very well be that this is a bug n my side related to outdated versions of `DT` and friends.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just tested and this seems to be a bug related to the use of the FixedColumns extension. Please see my edit. I filed another [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/929) regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

The following example adds a `<input type="text">` element to each row of the table, where you can add your free text. A simple `JavaScript` event listener reacts on changes to the text boxes and stores them in the `Shiny` variable `free_text` which you can then process on the shiny side according to your needs (in this toy example it is simply output to a `verbatimTextOutput`).

As for the storing: I would add a `save` button, which reads `input$free_text` and saves it back to the data base. To display the text then again in the text boxes is as easy as adding the value in the `mutate` statement like this `mutate(free_text = sprintf("<input type=\"text\" class = \"free-text\" value = \"%s\" />", free_text_field_name))`

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$head(
      tags$script(
         HTML(
            "$(function() {
               // input event fires for every change, consider maybe a debounce
               // or the 'change' event (then it is only triggered if the text box
               // loses focus)
               $('#tab').on('input',  function() {
                  const inputs = $(this).find('.free-text').map(function() {
                     return this.value;
                  })
                  Shiny.setInputValue('free_text', inputs.get());
               })
            })
            "
         )
      )
   ),
   fluidRow(
      verbatimTextOutput("out")
   ),
   fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput("tab")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$tab <- renderDataTable({
      my_dat <- mtcars %>% 
         mutate(free_text = 
                   sprintf("<input type=\"text\" class = \"free-text\" value = \"\" />"))
      datatable(my_dat, escape = FALSE, 
                options = list(dom = "t", pageLength = nrow(mtcars)))
   })
   
   output$out <- renderPrint(input$free_text)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the `handsontable` package, which allows editing of (columns of) datatable outputs. In your case, you can create a character column and allow editing through the handsontable.

On the topic of persisting data: you table would need either a separate column with comments, or a separate table that maps observations to comment, which is joined. The best solution depends on the volume of comments you expect: if you expect comment to appears sporadically, a separate table may be the best solution. If you expect comments for nearly every row, direct integration into the table may be more favourable. It then becomes a matter of writing to and loading from an SQL database based on user events.