# Download filtered table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm looking to create a Shiny app where I can download a table created with DT after applying filters. I would like to know if there is a way, after filtering, as in the column below, to click on the download button and download the entire filtered dataset. And the code should allow this regardless of the column where the filter is applied.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl'),downloadButton("downloadData", " Download", icon = icon("download"))),
 
   server = function(input, output) {
       datasetInput <- iris
       output$tbl = renderDT(
           datasetInput %>% mutate_at(vars(5), as.factor), options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),  filter = 'top',
         )
       output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
           filename = function() {
             paste("Data.csv")
             },
           content = function(file) {
               write.csv(datasetInput(), file)
             }
         )
```

}
)

[image]

As shown in the image, my goal is to arrive at a code where, when I click the download button, the results of this filter are downloaded. I would be very grateful for any help with this objective.

Comment: a post here might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670979/save-changes-made-to-a-reactive-dataframe-via-shiny-datatable-in-the-dt-package/77671000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        DTOutput('tbl'),
        downloadButton("download", " Download", icon = icon("download"))
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        datasetInput <- iris

        output$tbl = renderDT(
            datasetInput %>% mutate(across(5, as.factor)),
            options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),
            filter = 'top'
        )

        output$download <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                paste("Data.csv")
            },
            content = function(file) {
                selected_rows <- input$tbl_rows_all
                filtered_data <- datasetInput[selected_rows, ]
                write.csv(filtered_data, file, row.names = FALSE)
            }
        )
    }
)
```